# How do I get a list of all todo items in a CalDAV calendar from Perl?

Tags: perl, caldav

I've got a CalDAV calendar, and want to pull out all todo items from it, then delete them.

Either the Cal::DAV or HTTP::DAV module is possibly the way to go, but it's not at all clear how to do what I want, without learning a lot about CalDAV, which I'm hoping to avoid :-)

Comment: Does this have to be Perl? Otherwise you can just use Cadaver to connect to the todolist collection and do a 'rm *' ...

Comment: Well if you can show me the sequence to do in Cadaver, I can wrap Perl around that :-) I had a quick look at cadaver last night, can't remember why I gave up on it.

Comment: Cadaver is an interactive tool not suitable for wrapping. I wasn't sure whether you want to do this just once (in a bulk way) or really build into a script. @harvey's answer should do what you want. A CalDAV todo list is just a WebDAV collection. You retrieve the item URLs via a simple PROPFIND and you can delete them via a regular HTTP DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using raw sockets to connect and send the request manually - I found using a library like lwp, or http just gets cumbersome with the need for overriding the headers.

Referenced the request format from http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict 'vars';
use warnings;
use Socket;

# initialize host and port
my $host = 'www.example.com';
my $port =  80;

# contact the server
open_tcp(F, $host, $port) 
  or die 'Could not connect to server';

# Send request data
while ( my $request = <DATA> ) {
  print F $request;
}

# Get Response
while ( my $response = <F> ) {
  print "Response:> $response";
}

close(F);

# TCP Helper
sub open_tcp
{
  # get parameters
  my ($FS, $dest, $port) = @_;

  my $proto = getprotobyname('tcp');
  socket($FS, PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, $proto);
  my $sin = sockaddr_in($port,inet_aton($dest));
  connect($FS,$sin);

  my $old_fh = select($FS); 
  $| = 1; # don't buffer output
  select($old_fh);
}

__DATA__
REPORT /calendars/johndoe/home/ HTTP/1.1
Depth: 1
Prefer: return-minimal
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8

<c:calendar-query xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:c="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
    <d:prop>
        <d:getetag />
        <c:calendar-data />
    </d:prop>
    <c:filter>
        <c:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
            <c:comp-filter name="VTODO" />
        </c:comp-filter>
    </c:filter>
</c:calendar-query>
```

Comment: Thanks - this has got me part way there. The server I'm talking to uses https, so I've created something based on HTTP::Tiny. I get a response back from the CalDAV server, but not the expected VTODO items...